# How to append to properties in config.properties in Karaf in the /etc/config.properties file?

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

In Karaf there are two files in /etc/config, they are `config.properties` and `custom.properties`. As I read in config.properties I should override values in `custom.properties`. I wish to append to the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` key.

However I don't understand how I can append to this, I can of course completely copy its value across to custom.properties and add a value to it, but then its really big in `custom.properties`. In `custom.properties` I would like to have something simple like:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra = \
    universe.microservice.shared.service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to append to a value of the key. If there was there should also be a way to "insert" and "remove" values, which is far more complex.

Simply copy the key with it's default values and modify it any way you wish. The fact you have this in separate file (`custom.properties`) is a nice way to keep your changes aside. You can always `diff` the two files to check what have you changed. This comes very handy when you decide to upgrade in the future.

Comment: Append would be nice as if I upgraded Karaf, I would want to keep my custom properties around but allow Karaf it upgrade its properties